# Diffrence between sum of two products > 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, select

[image: I Have 2 columns in a table in MySQL]

I want to select the sum of T_No where Transactions are equal to R and subtract it by T_No where Transactions are equal to D and the answer of this should greater than zero for a CustomerID which would be a input (an int input declared in a stored procedure)

```
((Sum(T_No) where Transactions = R - Sum(T_No) where Transactions = D ) > 0) where CoustomerID = @input

Example : for ID = 1 it would be ((20+15) - 10) > 0
```

I Have tried so many things but either syntax is wrong, wrong value or it does not accept, and I am literally Stuck, this was my final attempt

```
SELECT 
(select ( select Sum(T_No) where Transactions = R) - (select Sum(T_No) where Transactions = D) as C_T ) 
FROM CustomerTrans WHERE C_T > 0 ;
```

Comment: See about conditional statements (i.e. CASE)

Comment: And for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Cannot be both mysql and sql-server.Decide which database you use please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should help:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction = 'R' THEN t_no ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction = 'D' THEN t_no ELSE 0 END) 
FROM CustomerTrans 
WHERE CoustomerID = @yourCustomerIdVariable
```

As you're writing a sproc you can assign the result of this to a variable and then decide what to do if the result is negative. (I would personally log an error for example, rather than just hide those results). If the result is null, then there were no transactions for that customer

ps; I used `Transaction` because that's what your screenshot showed, and I figured a screenshot is less likely to contain a typo than code with syntax errors. Adjust if required

Answer (score 1):

you where kinda close, I would sum like you, only the syntax is a bit off, you can't have aggregate fields in Where, thats why you should use having, also case when syntax is not correct.

```
Select
CoustomerID,
Sum(case when Transactions = 'R' then T_No else 0 end) -
Sum(case when Transactions = 'D' then T_No else 0 end) as C_T
FROM CustomerTrans
group by CoustomerID
having (Sum(case when Transactions = 'R' then T_No else 0 end) -
Sum(case when Transactions = 'D' then T_No else 0 end))>0
```